Ignore the use of a C++ function during compilation having operator<<
I'm developing an API looking like GLib logging.
My API can also disable these functions when the flag -DDEBUG isn't passed to GCC.
That means, there are no residues in the binary, all these debug functions including their parameters aren't present in the executable if this flag isn't passed.
It works perfectly in C, because it's macro functions I can easily replace ;
Example in C
debug.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "term.h"

/**
 * @brief Print something in debug mode
 * @details No loglevel/context
 * @param format
 * @param ... Parameters for format
 */
#define printf_debug(fmt, ...)

#define LOG_NONE 0
#define LOG_FATAL 1
#define LOG_ERROR 2
#define LOG_WARNING 3
#define LOG_INFO 4
#define LOG_DEBUG 5
#define LOG_TRACE 6

#if (defined(DEBUG))
#undef printf_debug

#define printf_debug(format, ...) \
    fprintf(stderr, "        " format "\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif // (defined(DEBUG))

main.c
#include <debug/debug.h>

int main()
{
    printf_debug("Hello world !");      // Show in any debug context

    return 0;
}

If I compile without the flag -DDEBUG, neither my macro function printf_debug() nor the string "Hello" remains.

I would have like to do the same in C++ with the << operator (such as std::cout works), but I can't manage << operator like I manage parameters in C.
Here's what I have tried ;
debug.hpp
#include <iostream>

#define LOG_UNDEFINED (-1)
#define LOG_NONE 0
#define LOG_FATAL 1
#define LOG_ERROR 2
#define LOG_WARNING 3
#define LOG_INFO 4
#define LOG_DEBUG 5
#define LOG_TRACE 6

namespace debug
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    class debug_cout
        : public std::ostream
    {
    public:
        debug_cout(std::streambuf *sbuf)
            : std::ios(sbuf), std::ostream(sbuf)
        {}
        ~debug_cout() {}
    };

    debug_cout cout(int l) {
        static int level = l;
        return debug_cout(std::cout.rdbuf());
    }
#else
    class debug_cout
        : public std::ostream
    {
    public:
        debug_cout() {}
        ~debug_cout() {}
    };

    debug_cout cout(int l) {
        return debug_cout();
    }
#endif
}

main.cpp
#include <debug/debug.hpp>


int main() {
    debug::cout(LOG_ERROR) << "Hello " << 3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

It compiles correctly this way ;
Using -DDEBUG flag, it outputs ;
Hello 3

Without -DDEBUG, it outputs nothing, but there are residues in the executable. I see using objdump my functions debug::cout() remains and is called.
I have also tried using GCC optimization flag -O3.

So my question ; Is it possible to ignore these instructions in C++ ? The ones having << operator.
Note: It's not an issue if I can't use namespace
Note 2: When I talk about residues I mean my function debug::cout() remains in the executable in C++ and is executed (and it just does nothing).

For a start, don't use reserved identifiers as include guards. Especially not one with such a generic name.

Which residues do you mean? Have you enabled compiler and linker optimizations?


Is it possible to ignore these instructions in C++

Yes. if constexpr can eliminate entire branches of code:
#ifdef DEBUG
#  define DEBUG_COUT(level)   if constexpr (0) {} else real_stream{level}
#else
#  define DEBUG_COUT(level)   if constexpr (1) {} else null_stream{level}
#endif

And use it like this:
DEBUG_COUT(5) << "Hello, " << 5 << " Worlds\n";

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/7j6drn9ec
P.S. Different definitions of the same class depending on some macro? That's a recipe for wonderful bugs in case of linking wrong library/object. Don't do that.

@TedLyngmo It's here to prevent not only evaluation, but also compilation of the else branch when no logging is desired. My understanding of OP's desire to get rid of "residues" is that no code, not even constructing the stream object, should be present in the object file.

Yeah, I got it. It was the top one that threw me off guard. I guess that could just be real_stream{level}. No constexpr if needed there.

@TedLyngmo, I want that macro to expand to a statement in both cases. I don't want it to expand to either statement or expression.

Very nice ! Thank you, works perfectly

My API is only supposed to enable/disable logging depending of this macro (using these 2 classes). There are nothing to link, only the header to include. This way there shouldn't be any issue isn't it ?

@Mike, There's always something to link. You header will be included in source files written by other people, and they may have something to link... I'm just saying that sticking to the One Definition Rule will keep you out of harm's way come what may. But you're a better judge of your project, so if you think it's safe -- that's ok.

Your non-logging debug_cout shouldn't inherit from std::ostream. Instead implement empty functions for streaming that does nothing. That should be easy for the compiler to optimize away:
class debug_cout {
public:
    template <class T>
        requires requires(T t) { std::cout << t; }
    debug_cout& operator<<(T&&) {
        return *this;
    }

    debug_cout& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) {
        return *this;
    }

    debug_cout& operator<<(std::ios& (*)(std::ios&)) { return *this; }

    debug_cout& operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&)) {
        return *this;
    }
};

Demo

Although I didn't mark your answer as the solution, I upvoted because although the function remains in the binary, the calls are removed with the flag -O3. And it keeps the namespace, that it pretty elegant

#else
    class debug_cout
        : public std::ostream

Your NDEBUG dummy object is an ostream. That's not nothing!
Even if the streambuf isn't connected to anything, that can change (and must therefore be checked) at runtime. You already know this, because you're setting the same streambuf up at runtime in the DEBUG branch.
You want a type that does nothing, so just write that:
#else
    class debug_cout {};

and you want it to work with stream insertion syntax, so write that:
    template <class T>
    debug_cout& operator<<(debug_cout& s, T&&)
    {
        return s;
    }

